# How we can export data in PDF format in lightning web Component?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, lightning, pdf

html:-

```
    <template>
    <lightning-card title="Account to Contact Communication in LWC" icon- 
    name="standard:contact">

     <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
            <lightning-combobox name="stageName" label="Satge Name" value= 
     {selectedStageName}
                placeholder="Select Stage Name" options={stageName}
                onchange={handleOpportunityStageNameChange}></lightning-combobox>&nbsp;

            <lightning-input type="text" label="Account Name" value={objAccount.Name} 
      data-formfield="accountName"
                name="accountName"></lightning-input>&nbsp;

            <lightning-input type="Percent" label="Probability" value={probability} 
       name="probability"
                onchange={handleChangeActionProb}></lightning-input>&nbsp;

            <lightning-input type="Date" label="Enter Start Date" value={oldDate} 
        name="oldDate"
                onchange={handleChangeAction}></lightning-input>&nbsp;

            <lightning-input type="Date" label="Enter End Date" value={oldDate2} 
         name="oldDate2"
                onchange={handleChangeAction}></lightning-input>
          </div>
          <br /> <br />
        <lightning-button type="brand" icon-name="utility:search" label="Show Data" 
       variant="brand" size="small"
            onclick={searchAction}></lightning-button>&nbsp;

        <lightning-button label="Clear Date" variant="brand" icon-name="utility:refresh"
            onclick={refreshComponent}></lightning-button>&nbsp;

        <lightning-button icon-name="utility:download" label="Export Excel" 
     title="Export Excel"
            onclick={downloadCSVFile} variant="brand"></lightning-button>&nbsp;

            <lightning-button label="Export PDF" variant="brand" onclick={saveAsPdf} 
            icon-name="utility:download" title="Export PDF" ></lightning-button>

        <br /> <br />

        <!--<lightning-datatable key-field="Id" data={oppListDate} columns={columns} 
        draft-values={draftValues}
            onrowselection={selectedRecordsHandler} onsave={saveHandler}>
         </lightning-datatable>-->

          <template if:true={showTableFlag}>
            <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered" 
           border="1" cellspacing="0"
                cellpadding="0" bordercolor="#ccc" style="border-collapse:collapse;">

                <thead>

                    <tr>

                        <th>Opportunity Name</th>

                        <th>Stage Name</th>

                        <th>Probability</th>

                        <th>Account Name</th>

                    </tr>

                  </thead>

                  <tbody>

                    <template for:each={oppListDate} for:item="oppItem">

                        <tr key={oppItem.Id}>

                            <td>{oppItem.Name}</td>

                            <td>{oppItem.StageName}</td>

                            <td>{oppItem.Probability}</td>

                            <td>{oppItem.Account.Name}</td>

                        </tr>

                      </template>
 
                     </tbody>

               </table>
             </template>
       </div>
        </lightning-card>
      </template>
```

JS:-

```
  import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
  import searchOpp from '@salesforce/apex/LwcDateCmpCtrl.searchOpp';

   export default class LwcSearchDate extends LightningElement {

  @track oldDate;
  @track oldDate2;
  @track oppListDate;
  @track errorMsg;
  @track recordId;
  @track oppListData;
  @track accountName
  @track probability;
  @track selectedOppStageName;
  showTableFlag = false;

  columnHeader = ['ID', 'Name', 'StageName', 'Probability', 'Account.Name' ]

   @track objAccount = {'sobjectType' : 'Account'}

   get stageName() {
      return [
        { label: 'Prospecting', value: 'Prospecting' },
        { label: 'Qualification', value: 'Qualification' },
        { label: 'Needs Analysis', value: 'Needs Analysis' },
        { label: 'Value Proposition', value: 'Value Proposition' },
        { label: 'Id. Decision Makers', value: 'Id. Decision Makers' },
        { label: 'Perception Analysis', value: 'Perception Analysis' },
        { label: 'Proposal/Price Quote', value: 'Proposal/Price Quote' },
        { label: 'Negotiation/Review', value: 'Negotiation/Review' },
        { label: 'Closed Won', value: 'Closed Won' },
        { label: 'Closed Lost', value: 'Closed Lost' },
        { label: 'Awaiting Approval', value: 'Awaiting Approval' },
        
      ];
  }


   searchAction(){

    console.log('searchAction ##' );

    this.objAccount.Name = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input[data- 
formfield="accountName"]').value

    searchOpp({dateStr1 : this.oldDate, dateStr2: this.oldDate2, objAcc : 
  this.objAccount, Prob : this.probability, stageName : this.selectedOppStageName})
      .then(result => {
        console.log(this.result);
        this.result = result
        this.oppListDate = result;
        this.showTableFlag = true
         window.console.log('oppListDate ' + JSON.stringify(this.oppListDate));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.errorMsg = error.message;
        this.showTableFlag = false
        window.console.log(this.error);
       });

    }

   handleChangeAction(event){

    if(event.target.name == 'oldDate'){
        this.oldDate = event.target.value;  
       
        window.console.log('oldDate ##' + this.oldDate);
      }

    if(event.target.name == 'oldDate2'){
        this.oldDate2 = event.target.value;  
        window.console.log('oldDate2 ##' + this.oldDate2);
      }

   }

    handleChangeActionProb(event){
       this.probability = event.target.value
   }
  handleOpportunityStageNameChange(event){
    this.selectedOppStageName = event.target.value
    window.console.log('selectedOppStageName ## = ' + this.selectedOppStageName);
   }

  refreshComponent(event){
    eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");
   }

// this method validates the data and creates the csv file to download
downloadCSVFile(){

    console.log('downloadCSVFile ##' );

    // Prepare a html table
    let doc = '<table>';

   // Add styles for the table
   doc += '<style>';
   doc += 'table, th, td {';
   doc += '    border: 1px solid black;';
   doc += '    border-collapse: collapse;';
   doc += '}';          
   doc += '</style>'; 

    // Add all the Table Headers
    doc += '<tr>';
    this.columnHeader.forEach(element => {            
        doc += '<th>'+ element +'</th>'           
    });
    doc += '</tr>';
    // Add the data rows
    this.oppListDate.forEach(oppItem => {
        doc += '<tr>';
        doc += '<th>'+oppItem.Id+'</th>'; 
        doc += '<th>'+oppItem.Name+'</th>'; 
        doc += '<th>'+oppItem.StageName+'</th>';
        doc += '<th>'+oppItem.Probability+'</th>';
        doc += '<th>'+oppItem.Account.Name+'</th>'; 
        doc += '</tr>';
    });
    doc += '</table>';
    var element = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(doc);
    let downloadElement = document.createElement('a');
    downloadElement.href = element;
    downloadElement.target = '_self';
    // use .csv as extension on below line if you want to export data as csv
    downloadElement.download = 'Opportunity Data.xls';
    document.body.appendChild(downloadElement);
    downloadElement.click();
}

saveAsPdf(){
    
}

actionToPublishedNav(event) {

  } 
 }
```

Comment: @sanketkumar Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jsPDF library to generate the pdf. It provides lots of inbuilt functions to create the pdf.

You can download the library from - https://unpkg.com/browse/jspdf@2.5.1/

Examples -
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf

There are other libraries too like - PDFKit, pdfmake, Puppeteer, pdf-lib, pdfme.

Due to the lightning locker service, most client-side libraries are blocked. We can use jsPDF library but a few functionalities like HTML to pdf generation will not work in Salesforce as dependent libraries are blocked by lightning locker.

Add jsPDF libraries in Static Resources

```
import jsPDF from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jsPDF';

connectedCallBack(){
   Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, jsPDF+'/jspdf.umd.min.js').then(() => {
                console.log("JS loaded");
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error("Error " + error);
            })
        ]);
}

// Access the jsPDF library using the window object.
const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
```